# How to mock ERP system in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, mocking, erp

I'm working on adding JUnit test to an enterprise solution's web services. My question is; how do I - if possible - mock the ERP system in the JUnit tests?

For example I have a `getOrders(Connection con, String customerId)` method. It, however, makes one call to the ERP system to list all orders like:

```
public List<Order> getOrders(Connection con, String customerId) {
  // Call ERP system
  orders = con.fetchOrders(customerId);

  // Manipulate result
  orders...

  return orders;      
}
```

Any way to mock the ERP connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean mock the Connection object?  It's unclear if Connection is an interface or a class.  Some mock object libraries only work on interfaces.  Here are some of the more popular Java mock object libraries [jmock](http://jmock.org/), [mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) and [easymock](http://easymock.org/)

The basic idea would be to create a mock `Connection` object and have it return data that you want to test.

For example using easymock:

```
String customerId =...
List<Order> myOrders = ...

Connection mockConnection = EasyMock.createMock(Connection.class);

EasyMock.expect(mockConnection.fetchOrders(customerId)).andReturn(myOrders);
EasyMock.replay(mockConnection);

//call system under test:
List<Orders> results = getOrders(mockConnection, customerId);

List<Orders> expectedResults = ....

assertEquals(expectedResults, results);
```

Comment: Thank you, this best suits my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If `Connection` is an interface, then you can simply use something similar to [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) to verify the messages that are sent to it.

If `Connection` is a concrete class then it's more difficult.  I'd create an interface that duplicated the connection classes public methods and delegated to the appropriate ERP `Connection` instance.

```
interface ERPConnection {
   List<Order> fetchOrders(String customerID);
}

class MyConnection implements ERPConnection {
    private Connection _conn;

    public List<Order> fetchOrders(string customerID) {
      return _conn.fetchOrders(customerID);
    }
}
```

Now in your code you'll rely on the `ERPConnection` interface rather than the `Connection` concrete class.  This'll feel like a lot of changes, but it'll insulate you from changes to the ERP system and allow you to mock the interface and test the interaction.

Comment: That's clever. Feel stupid not to think of it myself.. ;) I'll check the code tomorrow and see if it's possible.